# Text recognition from binary image using matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, binary

I wanna extract numbers and basic operators from binary image, i've tried region of interest but it fails with me, and connected components in matlab using this function `bwconncomp` but it produces a structure of cells not the image objects.
Can anyone help me to recognize the numbers from this image using matlab?

[image]

Comment: what about https://de.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/ocr.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an overview to help you out.

Use [`bwlabel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html) to get a labeled image. Use the label image to extract each connected object (including the numbers). For each object in the image, you can know the max/min x and y so you can extract a smaller image. Use that image for your classifier to decide what number it is (if it is a number).

Comment: @ZeyadEtman First invert your image. Background = black, objects = white.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try a OCR.
Look this link: [OCR MatLab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/ocr.html)

Example:

```
I=imread('image.png');
ocrResults = ocr(I);
```

Then on variable ocrResults, there will be a field called "Text" with the numbers detected